# Determine each character of a string if it contains full width characters

Tags: java

I want to manually check each character of a `string` for whether it contains any full width characters. Can someone help me?

This is what I have so far:

```
public boolean areAnyFullWidth(String input) {
    for (char c : input.toCharArray())
        if ((c & 0xff00) == 0xff00)
            return true;
        return false;
}
```

Comment: what does full width means ?

Comment: full width characters are letters or numbers like this ａｓｄ１２３－４５

Comment: I just follow the instruction in this link  sir [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508932/how-check-if-string-has-full-width-character-in-java)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt When i say letters or numbers like this I mean characters that taking a much wider space in computer compare to a normal one

Comment: I just found that link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508932/how-check-if-string-has-full-width-character-in-java - so, it completely describes how to check for "full width" characters. What specific question do you have that is *not* answered by that post?

Comment: I want to restrict an input string with full width characters regarding of what character is it. His code accept full width characters like chinese and japanese letters

Comment: @healer Ok, if that's what your issue is, **edit** (see link under) the question and put it in there.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the start and end unicode full width range then things are very simple.

Say the range is 0xFFOO to 0xFFEF:

```
public boolean areAnyFullWidth(String input) {
    for(char c : input.toCharArray())
        if(c >= 0xFFOO && c <= 0xFFEF)
            return true;
        return false;
}
```