# Convert fullwidth string into halfwidth string

Tags: r, regex

How can I convert `Ａb９８７６５４３２１０` into `Ab9876543210`? Is there a solution by regular expression?

`test <- dput("Ａb９８７６５４３２１０")`

Comment: Not sure what exactly you meant.  Both the strings look the same except the format

Comment: I see this question discussed before for java [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508932/how-check-if-string-has-full-width-character-in-java), but I've never come across this in R. Can you provide your full width string using `dput`? If I copy & paste into my console, it's the same as normal text...

Comment: @Z.Lin I change my code, can you see the full-width string?

Comment: I was able to semi-reproduce your problem, by copying the fullwidth string to a text file, save it with UTF-8 encoding, then load it into R with encoding specified as such. Copying it directly into R doesn't work, nor does typing full width text (I switched to pinyin mode & toggled on fullwidth). I'll try to see what I can come up with.

Comment: For anyone else interested to try this, the dput result of the full width string on my machine is "<U+FEFF>Ab9876543210"

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: The following works on my machine, but since I can't replicate your full width string based purely on the example provided, this is a best guess based on my version of the problem (pasting the string into a text file, save it with UTF-8 encoding, & loading it in with coding specified as UTF-8.*

**Step 1**. Reading in the text (I added a half width version for comparison):

```
> test <- readLines("fullwidth.txt", encoding = "UTF-8")
> test
[1] "﻿Ａb９８７６５４３２１０" "Ab9876543210"
```

**Step 2**. Verifying that the full & half width versions are not equal:

```
# using all.equal()
test1 <- test[1]
test2 <- test[2]
> all.equal(test1, test2)
[1] "1 string mismatch"

# compare raw bytes
> charToRaw(test1)
 [1] ef bb bf ef bc a1 62 ef bc 99 ef bc 98 ef bc 97 ef bc 96 ef bc 95 ef
[24] bc 94 ef bc 93 ef bc 92 ef bc 91 ef bc 90
> charToRaw(test2)
 [1] 41 62 39 38 37 36 35 34 33 32 31 30
```

*For anyone interested, if you paste the raw byte version into a [utf-8 decoder](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder) as hexadecimal input, you'll see that except for letter b (mapped from 62 in the 7th byte), the rest of the letters were formed by 3-byte sequences. In addition, the first 3-byte sequence maps to "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE character", so it's not visible when you print the string to console.*

**Step 3**. Converting from full width to half width using the `Nippon` package:

```
library(Nippon)
test1.converted <- zen2han(test1)

> test1.converted
[1] "﻿Ab9876543210"

# If you want to compare against the original test2 string, remove the zero 
# width character in front
> all.equal(substring(test1.converted, 2), test2)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R solution

Full width characters are in the range `0xFF01:0xFFEF`, and can be offset like this.

```
x <- "Ａb９８７６５４３２１０"
iconv(x, to = "utf8") |>
  utf8ToInt() |>
  (\(.) ifelse(. > 0xFF01 & . <= 0xFFEF, . - 65248, .))() |>
  intToUtf8()

[1] "Ab9876543210"
```